# How to refresh relationships based on _id (none-transient) with objects fetched out of sync

Tags: objective-c, rest, core-data, restkit, restkit-0.20

I have the following model:

```
@interface EquipmentModel : NSManagedObject

@property (nonatomic, retain) NSDate * creationDate;
@property (nonatomic, retain) NSString * desc;
@property (nonatomic, retain) NSNumber * identifier;
@property (nonatomic, retain) NSDate * lastModifiedDate;
@property (nonatomic, retain) NSString * name;
@property (nonatomic, retain) NSNumber * manufacturerID;
@property (nonatomic, retain) Manufacturer *manufacturer;
```

I fetch that object using RESTKit and the following mapping:

```
RKEntityMapping *equipmentModelMapping = [RKEntityMapping mappingForEntityForName:@"EquipmentModel" inManagedObjectStore:managedObjectStore];
equipmentModelMapping.identificationAttributes = @[@"identifier"];
[equipmentModelMapping addAttributeMappingsFromDictionary:@{
 @"id": @"identifier",
 @"description": @"desc",
 @"manufacturer_id": @"manufacturerID",
 @"creation_date": @"creationDate",
 @"last_modified_date": @"lastModifiedDate",
 }];
[equipmentModelMapping addAttributeMappingsFromArray:@[ @"name"]];
[equipmentModelMapping addConnectionForRelationship:@"manufacturer" connectedBy:@{ @"manufacturerID": @"identifier"}];
```

However, it is possible that sometimes the manufacturers are not fetched **before** the models, and hence the relationship "manufacturer" relationship will equal to nil for the model, once the **getObjectsAtPath** call is completed. Since I made the manufacturerID none-transient, I will still have it store. How can I update the relationship then?

One possibility is to fetch the models once the manufacturers are fetch. However, I have other Objects that are more complex and such approach will not work and not be efficient. How can I link relationship in CoreData based on that ID?!

Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 0):

Your suggested solution is correct, you just want to choose how to predicate your fetches so that only the models that aren't connected are returned. You can also batch the fetches, updates and saves if there are a large number of items to process. There isn't a way to have Core Data or RestKit make the relationship for you in this case.